# Head.phtml shows twice in source code on category pages

Tags: magento, categories, head

In the source code the head.phtml is loaded twice, once the way it should be and once between the content and footer. I replaced all magento's original files on the server and temperary switched to the default template, wich didn't solve the problem.

See the following link:
http://www.qxsystems.net/laptops.html

I asume that the issue is coused by a module or by a magento setting in the backend.

Could somebody provide me with some ways of troubleshooting this issue without removing all modules?

Many thx for any assistance!

PS: A module was to blame: Named 'priceranges'

thx for all the help!

Comment: I cannot find wrong in the link..might be cache issue

Comment: Hey thx for the help! See the source code of the link and scroll al the way down. There you will see a double head.phtml starting with <title>Magento Commerce</title>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have replaced the original files and also changed the template and still no change then it is surely a cache issue. Refresh your cache.

If still doesn't solves your problem then it must be some external modules issue.

If the problem is not solved then give a screenshot of your webpage with TemplatePathHints turned on, then it will be easier to tell where exactly is the problem.

Comment: Thx I found some additional info : it only happens with pages that have layered navigation, a module named manna is used for layered navigation. Disabling doesnt solve the problem. I recompiled, reindexed and of cource empty'd cache more than once.. PS: I enabled template path hints for you guys to see !

Comment: I can see the source code.. you solved it. congrats. What was the problem btw ?

Comment: A module was to blame: Named 'priceranges'